# Creating like and dislike buttons in html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm creating these two like and dislike buttons.

[image]

I'm having an issue when I set the width of the buttons to `48%` to make them fill up the containing `div`, then they are displayed like the following.
[image]

How can I display the circular `span` at the end like above? after setting the width to `48%`.

code for the buttons.

```
 <button class="social-like" >
     <span class="like"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></span>
     <span class="count" >0</span>
 </button>
    &nbsp;
 <button class="social-dislike" >
     <span class="dislike" >0</span>
     <span class="like"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i></span>
</button>
```

my css

```
.social-like, .social-dislike {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    /*width: 48%;*/
    background-color: #03A9F4;
    color: #fff;
}

.social-like {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.social-dislike {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.count, .like, .dislike {
    padding:10px;
}

.count, .dislike {
    background-color: #03A9F4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size:12px;
}

.dislike {
    margin-left: -13px;
}

.count {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

And also how can I make the like and dislike buttons to have a clickable effect?

[example on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phutis/DTcHh/26208/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text-align

```
.social-like {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}

.social-dislike {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26211/)

**EDIT**
You can choose any type of effect you like, this is the target css for it, change the `color`, `font-size` or `margin` ect...

```
.like:focus,
.like:active,
.dislike:focus,
.dislike:active {
    //effect goes here
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26212/)

Comment: Thanks, how can I add a clickable effect to the like and dislike icons?

Comment: only to the icons? @julekgwa

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use an `<a>` tag instead of a `<button>`. It's not exactly what you asked for, but it might be an option if you cannot find a solution to this.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26213/

```
<a class="social-like" >
                    <span class="like"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></span>
                    <span class="count" >15</span>
                </a>
                &nbsp;
                <a class="social-dislike" >
                    <span class="dislike" >10</span>
                    <span class="like"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i></span>
                </a>
```

I added some classes to your demo:

```
.social-like:hover, .social-dislike:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}

.social-like:active, .social-dislike:active {
  background-color: #3299CD;
}

.social-like:active .count, .social-dislike:active .dislike {
  background-color: #3299CD;
}
```